# Method not returning the expected value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I was trying to implement Karatsuba multiplication in Ruby..

```
# takes two integer x and y and partition them to x=a+b and y=c+d
# example if x = 1234 a=12 and b=34
# recursively compute a*c,a*d,b*c and b*d
def mult (x,y)
    if len(x) == 1 && len(y) == 1
             return  x*y 
       elsif len(x) > 1 && len(y) > 1
             ab = partition(x)
             cd =  partition(y)
             return ab.product(cd).each{ |num| mult(num[0],num[1]) }
       end
end
#method for partitioning works fine..
def partition(number)
     number.divmod( 10**(len(number)/2) )
end
#method to find size of integer works fine...
def len(value)
    value.to_s.split("").compact.size
end
```

So the expected return for

```
 p mult(12,34) should be 3,4,6,8
 but is [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

instead of `return x*y`, when i use `print "#{x*y}"` in `line no:3` it prints 3,4,6,8. I am unable to understand why `mult` method is returning `nil` for `x*y`.

Comment: `len(x)`? That sounds like Python

Comment: @Ursus it sounds like self-implemented method, check the last 3 lines of the snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is wrong iterator:

```
#              ⇓⇓⇓⇓    
ab.product(cd).each{ |num| mult(num[0],num[1]) }
```

What you want is to [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) instead:

```
ab.product(cd).map { |num| mult(num[0], num[1]) }
```

*Sidenote:* you also don’t need to explicitly call `return`:

```
def mult (x,y)
  if len(x) == 1 && len(y) == 1
    x*y
  elsif len(x) > 1 && len(y) > 1
    ab = partition(x)
    cd = partition(y)
    ab.product(cd).map { |num| mult(num[0], num[1]) }
  else
    raise "We got a problem"
  end
end
#method for partitioning works fine..
def partition(number)
  number.divmod( 10**(len(number)/2) )
end
#method to find size of integer works fine...
def len(value)
  value.to_s.size
end

p mult 12, 34
#⇒ [3,4,6,8]
```

Comment: thanks its working I should have known when it printed `[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]` and stopped

Comment: but why isn't `each` working when I have to just iterate over each value and pass it to `mult(x,y)` method.

Comment: Because `each` returns the iterable itself, while `map` actually transforms the iterable to new values, returned from the `mult` method.